# How to use ORM for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have my SQL Server database - how should I use model query instead of raw query in node js express framework. Is there any way that we can create models for the tables and fetch the result?

Answer (score 0):

ORMs or Object Relational Models are used to interact and perform CRUD operations on a DB server without writing out raw query.
Sequelize is a pretty good ORM for SQL databases in node.js

Read the documentation or checkout a video on youtube on how to create models in Sequelize

Official Website:
https://sequelize.org/

NPM page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Comment: Can you please send an example how to implement